# Trying to get a list of objects ordered by sum of an attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql, express

In an express api I am using a raw query on a postgres db. I have a model Acts, and I created a leaderboard which ranks users (members of a group) by the number of acts they logged in a period of days (:points_horizon).
here is that query:

```
SELECT memberships.users_id
    ,users.username
    ,avatar_url
    ,COUNT(acts.users_id)
FROM memberships
JOIN groups ON memberships.groups_id = groups.id
JOIN users ON memberships.users_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN acts ON acts.users_id = users.id
    AND acts.created_at >= (CURRENT_DATE - 1 - '+ JSON.parse(req.query.group).points_horizon + ')
WHERE memberships.groups_id = ' + req.params.group_id + '
GROUP BY memberships.users_id
    ,users.username
    ,avatar_url
ORDER BY COUNT(acts.id) DESC;
```

However, I am trying to create a score where acts have different values held in an attribute called `deed_points`. this is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT memberships.users_id
    ,users.username
    ,avatar_url
    ,SUM(acts.deed_points)
FROM memberships
JOIN groups ON memberships.groups_id = groups.id
JOIN users ON memberships.users_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN acts ON acts.users_id = users.id
    AND acts.created_at >= (CURRENT_DATE - 1 - '+ JSON.parse(req.query.group).points_horizon + ')
WHERE memberships.groups_id = ' + req.params.group_id + '
GROUP BY memberships.users_id
    ,users.username
    ,avatar_url
ORDER BY SUM(acts.deed_points) DESC;
```

This is returning null values instead of the sum of deed_points.

in response to the comment, here are my table schemas:

users:

[image: users table schema]
groups:
[image: groups table schema]

memberships:
[image: memberships schema]

acts:

[image: acts schema]

deeds:
[image: deeds schema]

There is currently only one record in the acts db which has a deeds_id =1 and deed_points = 10

Comment: The record in your acts table must not match the `LEFT JOIN` condition.

Comment: Table definitions are better shown as `create table` statements and formatted text, not as screen shots